# Magento needs a storeview set to update attribute on website scope

Tags: magento

It seems like I have to set a store view before I can update an attribute on website scope – is that correct?

My code:

```
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load(123);
$product->setStoreId('1'); // without this line the attribute is not updated
$product->setSomeattribute("abc");
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. that's correct. This is for performance reasons on the frontend. Usually you don't save products from frontend. [See a detailed explanation of why is this needed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5246/146).
But you don't need to do that. I's slow and resource consuming. Try to save it like this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
    ->updateAttributes(array(123), array('somattribute'=>'abc'), 1);
```

The first parameter is and array with the product ids.
The second is an array with the attribute codes and values to be updated.
The third is the store id for which the update is done.

This method is faster.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try that. Btw... is it possible, that this worked different in earlier versions? My import script was running well without setting the storeId before I updated (from 1.4.some to 1.7.0.2)

Comment: @johjoh I think this restriction was added in 1.3 but I'm not sure.

Comment: Still not getting it. I didn't mean the `setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)` but `setStoreId('1')` ... used it like that, but now having problems with the images which are on website scope and so not updated there.